# Is it possible to change the rotation of fill curve node in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a mesh surface from a curve that I can move around and edit in the viewport, but there doesn't seem to be any input to change the axis the 'Fill Curve' projects from other than Z?

Is it possible to create the fill curve exactly where my curve location/rotation/scale is in the viewport?

[image]

Comment: Fill Curve is 2-dimensional, so it operates on $xy$ axes. You can rotate it temporarily to the $z=0$ plane, Fill Curve and rotate back.

Comment: In the documentation it says *The mesh is only generated flat with a local Z of 0.* https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/operations/fill_curve.html